# Web scraping instagram follower count and set it as discord channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to set a certain user's Instagram follower count as a discord channel which updates every 30 sec. I am facing an error with a package which seems to only work when i log it to terminal, not the actual discord.

[Package I am using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-basic-data-scraper-with-username).

Here is my code so far:

```
const config = require("./config.json");
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })

// Log stats-bot in to the server and set status
bot.on("ready", async () => {
console.log(`${bot.user.username} has logged on.`)
bot.user.setActivity('Half Life 3', { type: 'PLAYING' })
  .then(presence => console.log(`Activity set to ${presence.game ? presence.game.name : 'none'}`))
  .catch(console.error);

// Get our server
const guild = bot.guilds.get('875154076814438430');

// Get our stats channels

const instaObj = require('instagram-basic-data-scraper-with-username');

const user = 'milliontoken';


const totalUsers = bot.channels.get('875154076814438434');


// Check every 30 seconds for changes
setInterval(function() {

  //Get actual counts
  instaObj.getFollowers(user).then(res => {
    const getFollowers = res.data;
    console.log(getFollowers);
  });
  
  // Log counts for debugging
  console.log("Total Users: " + getFollowers);

  // Set channel names
  totalUsers.setName("Total Users: " + getFollowers)
  .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);

  }, 30000)

});

bot.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Constant variables can not be changed while the program is running. You have declared a constant `getFollowers` inside your interval loop. You program tries to change the value of your constant, but can't because it cannot be changed during runtime and throws an error.

Since you included no error data, this is the only thing I can see wrong with your code.

```js
// Check every 30 seconds for changes
setInterval(function() {

  //Get actual counts
  instaObj.getFollowers(user).then(res => {
    let getFollowers = res.data; //remove 'const', replace with non-constant declaration syntax
    console.log(getFollowers);
  });
  
  // Log counts for debugging
  console.log("Total Followers: " + getFollowers); //changed from "users" to "followers"

  // Set channel names
  totalUsers.setName("Total Followers: " + getFollowers)
  .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);

  }, 30000)

});
```

[Read this](https://press.rebus.community/programmingfundamentals/chapter/constants-and-variables/) - it will clear up any misinformation about constants and variables.

In future questions, please include error logs from console. It makes debugging your code infinitely easier.